# Transpose nested customDimension column data into rows Bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, transpose, unnest

My BigQuery table looks like below

```
Fullvisitorid   CustomDimension.Index   CustomDimension.value
   123                1                       red
                      2                       blue
                      3                       green
   456                1                       red
                      3                       orange
                      4                       black
```

I want my final output to look like below

```
 Fullvisitorid   Color1     Color2
     123           red       green    
     456           red       orange
```

Below is the query I have written but I am getting an error "FUNCTION NOT FOUND: FIRST"

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  FIRST(IF(customDimensions.index=1, customDimensions.value, NULL)) color1,
  FIRST(IF(customDimensions.index=3, customDimensions.value, NULL)) color2
  FROM `my_table`
  cross join
  unnest(customDimensions) customDimensions,
  unnest(hits) hits
  where customDimensions.index in (1,3)
   group by fullvisitorid
```

I Found a similar question which helped me write my query:

[[Transpose nested rows into columns in bigquery with google analytics data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29662325/transpose-nested-rows-into-columns-in-bigquery-with-google-analytics-data][1])

I am not sure why I am getting an error on my query. 
I would really appreciate any help!

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using #standardSQL now - that's good.

Instead of `FIRST()` use `ANY_VALUE()`.

I updated my answer in the referenced question accordingly:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/29664156/132438

Answer (score 1):

You can also create a User Defined Function and call it always you want a custom dimension:

```
SELECT
  fullvisitorid,
  PATH.CUSTOM_DIMENSION_BY_INDEX(1, h.customDimensions) AS color1,
  PATH.CUSTOM_DIMENSION_BY_INDEX(3, h.customDimensions) AS color2,
  FROM `my_table`
  cross join
  unnest(customDimensions) customDimensions,
  unnest(hits) hits
  where customDimensions.index in (1,3)
   group by fullvisitorid
```

Where PATH.CUSTOM_DIMENSION_BY_INDEX(index, h.customDimensions) is an UDF with format:

```
(SELECT x.value FROM UNNEST(arr) x WHERE indx=x.index)
```

You can find more information about it [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/user-defined-functions?hl=pt-br).